# Difficulty incorporated handlebars in node.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

**Hello everyone !**

Here I want incorporated 'express-handlebars' but I can not arrange it as I wish.
my app files:

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Importation :

// Framework Express:
const express = require('express')

// Express-handlebars:
const expressHb = require('express-handlebars')

// Instance de l'objet express :
const app = express()

// Route User:
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoute')

// Route Post:
const postRoute = require('./routes/postRoute')

// Route Comment:
const commentRoute = require('./routes/commentRoute')

// Package body-parser:
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') // Convertit le corp de la requéte en json en objet Js

// Mysql:
const connectDB = require('./config/connexion')

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Appelée à chaque requête envoyée au serveur:


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
) 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + './views'))

app.engine('hbs',
  expressHb( {
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: false,
    layoutsDir: "views/layouts/"
  })
)

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set("views", "views");

// Les routes:
// User:
app.use('/api/auth', userRoute);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Exportation:
module.exports = app
```

my routes files:

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Importation :

// Framework Express:
const express = require('express')
const app = require('../app')

// Création de gestionnaires de route modulaires:
const router = express.Router()

// PostController:
const userCtrl = require('../controllers/userCtrl')

// auth.js:
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')

const admin = require('../middleware/authAdmin')

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Routes:

// Signup:
router.post('/signup', userCtrl.signup)

// Login:
router.post('/login', userCtrl.login);

// Admin:
router.get('/', userCtrl.getUserProfil);
```

my controllers files:

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Importation :

// Import du models user:
const models = require('../models/user')

// dotEnv :
const dotEnv = require('dotenv').config()


// Fatest-validator: (validateur de saisie)
const Validator = require("fastest-validator");

// Bcrypt:
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

// Jsonwebtoken d'authentification:
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const uuid = require('uuid');


// Dashboard:
exports.getUserProfil = (req, res) => {

  res.render("home");
}
```

So when I put:

```js
app.get ('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render ("home");
})
```

in the app file it works but cannot put it in the controller it cannot find and sends me back:
'Cannot GET /'

my main.hbs file in the layout folder:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Administration</title>
</head>
<body>

  {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

my home.hbs file in the views folder:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Example App: Home</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and the tree structure of my files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pLMY.jpg)

Hoping that it is quite explicit, if need be clarified, do not hesitate
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the path of the request that is failing? ie., is it `/api/auth`?

Comment: @76484 Hello, thank you, on api/auth I have this error message: Cannot GET / ap% C3% AE / auth

Comment: nobody can help me ?  :(

Comment: It is very hard to isolate your issue because you have posted so much code. I would advise you narrow down your issue. Based on your "Cannot GET" errors, it looks very much like this is not to do with Handlebars but how you have implemented Express and your routers.

Comment: @76484 thank you for your feedback, in fact i don't know what i did and now it's working, ... thanks for your help.